# what happens if saml is missing one of default claims in saml & attributes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, claims-based-identity, claims

In azure portal what  happens if one of the default saml claims are missing like surname or given name or mail while integrating an app in Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody stumbles across this...

What happens is strictly up to the app being integrated when provisioning occurs. It could ignore the missing claim, or it could reject the assertion. In which case Azure will show the provisioning did not succeed.

And this is the same in any identity provider; it is up to the app, not the IdP!